# Does Microsoft Edge have a --silent-launch option like Chrome/Firefox and what is the correct syntax for it?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I want to launch Edge in the background without it showing up a window to the user. For Chrome it would be

```
chrome.exe --app="www.google.com"
```

and a silent window would be

```
chrome.exe --silent-launch="www.google.com"
```

So how would microsoft-edge: "www.google.com" have to be changed to do the same thing?

Comment: What is possible with Chrome, which is a Win32 application, is not typically possible with a UWP application like Edge.  What exactly makes you think Edge supports a silent launch?

Comment: I am not sure it does and I can't seem to locate any launch parameters besides dev-tools in the documentation.

Comment: Microsoft Edge is already running in the background : *Settings > Privacy > Background apps*. What do you want more?

Comment: I want to launch a page without it appearing on screen.